# How to append data to `from([urls])` and be dynamic with RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
const results = [];
from(generateUrls())
    .pipe(
     mergeMap( url => fetch(url), 4) 
  ).subscribe(result => {
    results.push(result);
 });


function generateUrls() {
  let urls = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
     urls.push(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i}`);
  }
  return urls;
}
```

How can I append some more urls to `from` if I need more data?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain - "How can I append some more URLs to from if I need more data?"

Comment: @user2216584 How do I add more urls after I reach the final (i=100) url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine an action stream (an add action) with your data stream. You can then continue to add items to your stream by adding items to the action stream.

Here is an example of one that I have that you can tailor to your specifications:

```
  // All products
  products$ = this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Products', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );

  // Action Stream
  private productInsertedSubject = new Subject<Product>();
  productInsertedAction$ = this.productInsertedSubject.asObservable();

  // Merge the streams
  productsWithAdd$ = merge(
    this.products$,
    this.productInsertedAction$
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((acc: Product[], value: Product) => [...acc, value]),
      catchError(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );

  addProduct(newProduct: Product) {
    this.productInsertedSubject.next(newProduct);
  }
```

Every time you need to add another item (product in this example), just call `addProduct` and pass it in.

UPDATE: I modified the above to match more closely with your application:

```
  results = [];

  // Data stream
  urls$ = from(this.generateUrls());

  // Action Stream
  private newUrlSubject = new Subject<string>();
  newUrlAction$ = this.newUrlSubject.asObservable();

  // Merge the streams
  urlsWithAdd$ = merge(
    this.urls$,
    this.newUrlAction$
  )
    .pipe(
      tap(url => console.log('url:', url)),
      mergeMap(url => this.http.get(url), 4),
      tap(result => this.results.push(result))
    );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, ) {
    this.urlsWithAdd$.subscribe();
  }

  generateUrls() {
    let urls = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
      urls.push(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i}`);
    }
    return urls;
  }

  addUrl(newUrl: string) {
    this.newUrlSubject.next(newUrl);
  }

  onClick() {
    this.addUrl(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/42`);
  }
}
```

You can find the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-adding-items-deborahk

NOTE: I was not able to use `fetch` as `fetch` returns a promise, not an Observable. Though you could try using `from(fetch(...))`?

Answer (score 2):

you can use BehaviorSubject to store the urls, then just use urls.next(..newUrl) to push item to the stream.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map,mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


const urls=new BehaviorSubject(null)

const results = [];
function generateUrl() {
  for(let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
     urls.next(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i}`);
  }
}

urls.pipe(
     mergeMap( url => fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()).catch(e=>e)

     , 4) 
  ).subscribe(result => {
    results.push(result);
    console.log(results)
 });

generateUrl()


setTimeout(()=>urls.next(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/10`),2000)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xw9dft

Comment: Can you show me a fuller example? How do I add more urls after I reach the final url?

Comment: modify the answer the add the example